# Collecting data from multiple div's and saving it as a list in txt (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file that creates any number of coupons with unique codes for printing on a thermal printer. A file has been created based on a script generating codes and a script that makes any number of coupons for solid printing (one page). Now I need that when opening this html file, all codes from coupons are saved in a list in txt. I found a script that works for me, it combines the codes into an array and colors them red. Help me fix the script so that instead of the red text, the list is saved to a txt file. Thank you all in advance for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('createcode');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.color = 'red';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript can't write directly to a text file as perhaps you are hoping but you can create a downloadable representation of a text file programmatically

Comment: `elements[i].style.color = 'red';` is a "write" operation, i.e. it sets a style on the element .... reading the value of an element is a little different and how to do it depends on the TYPE of element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timon_dev/doatqvec/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="createcode">Content1</div>
<div class="createcode">Content2</div>
<div class="createcode">Content3</div>
<div class="createcode">Content4</div>
<div class="createcode">Content5</div>
<div class="createcode">Content6</div>
<div class="createcode">Content7</div>
<div class="createcode">Content8</div>

<br><br>

<button id="download">
Download
</button>
```

Javascript

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".createcode");
var text = "";
elements.forEach(element => text += element.innerText + "\n");

function createAndDownloadTextFile (filename, text) {
    // Create a blob object representing the text file
    const blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });

    // Create an anchor element and use it to trigger the download
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    anchor.download = filename;

    // Append the anchor to the document and trigger the download, then remove the anchor
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}

document.getElementById("download")
.addEventListener("click", () => createAndDownloadTextFile('example.txt', text));
```

If you click the button you download a txt file with each div's content as a new line.

(I changed your given Code for selecting the div, but it does not matter. The important part is the function)

Comment: Have problem. My div createcode a have 2 div's: "<div id="createcode" class="createcode" style="display:flex;font-size:20px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;">
    <div id="leftcode" class="leftcode" style="float:left;">15-</div>
    <div id="generatecode" class="generatecode" style="float:right;"></div>
    </div>" If save txt i see "15-</br>code". How remove <br>?

Comment: in txt the code is split into two lines. first line "15-", second line "code". How can I save it in one line?